# C++, Casting a function pointer parameter

Tags: c++

I was trying to write a C++ program, including a header file, and a cpp file, plus, I am using the SimConnect dll.

Let's say I have a class called `MyClass`, which contains some functions.
Inside one of my functions, I call this SimConnect function:

```
SIMCONNECTAPI SimConnect_CallDispatch(HANDLE hSimConnect, DispatchProc pfcnDispatch, void * pContext);
```

Also, I wrote this function:

```
void __stdcall MyClass::myDispatchProc(SIMCONNECT_RECV* pData, DWORD cbData, void *pContext)
```

As far as I understood, I should send this function as the second parameter to the SimConnect function `SimConnect_CallDispatch` I talked about before.

I read an example which came with the SimConnect SDK which is doing exactly what I am doing, while I get an error, and they don't.
The only thing that's different is that they wrote their whole code in one page, while I tried to split the code into header + body.

When I try to do as I said above, and write

```
SimConnect_CallDispatch(hSimConnect, myDispatchProc, NULL);
```

I receive this error (compiler is having trouble in `myDispatchProc` part):

```
argument of type "void (__stdcall TransmitData::*)(SIMCONNECT_RECV *pData, DWORD cbData, void *pContext)" is incompatible with parameter of type "DispatchProc"
```

So clearly, it's a casting-like error.
As I said, this code would've worked if I didn't split my program into two separate files. Why doesn't it work now?

Comment: What is `DispatchProc`?

Comment: A pointer-to-member-function is not a pointer-to-function. You cannot pass a member function to a C-style interface that expects a C-style function pointer.

Comment: What @PeteBecker said, you could wrap it in a plain non-member function and pass that one to `SimConnect_CallDispatch`.

Comment: @daragua .. or a static function will do i think

Comment: A good run-down on what to do and what not to do with pointers to members: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: @ccpgh well yes, if it is really designed as a static method that is, which I supposed it wasn't :)

Comment: @ccpgh - technically, no; a static member function has C++ linkage, and C code requires C linkage. In practice this works.

Comment: @PeteBecker ok. i missed the c part. thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone, Ill try it out!

Answer (score 1):

#### Note: This question is specific to the [SimConnect SDK](https://docs.flightsimulator.com/html/Introduction/Introduction.htm) used for Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020

Although this is not a recent question, I'll leave a reference in case anyone else stumbles upon this.

The **[SimConnect_CallDispatch](https://docs.flightsimulator.com/html/Programming_Tools/SimConnect/API_Reference/General/SimConnect_CallDispatch.htm)** function requires a reference to a static, callback function with a specific interface, i.e. `(SIMCONNECT_RECV* pData, DWORD cbData, void* pContext)`

The nature of the static function is that it won't have access to the variables of the instance. So to get around this problem, all of the examples out there don't bother with the complexity of .h and .cpp files and just put everything in one file.

Let's say I have a class "MyClass" with separate .h and .cpp files. This is how I solved this issue,

###### 1. Define the Static Callback Function in the Header File

Define the default/standard static callback function for SimConnect in in the .h file, e.g.

```
void static CALLBACK MyDispatchProcRD(SIMCONNECT_RECV *pData, DWORD cbData, void *pContext);
```

###### 2. Define a Custom Instance Function in the Header File

To handle the processing of the callback in the actual instance and not through the static function, define a custom instance function in the .h file e.g.

```
void DispatchProc(SIMCONNECT_RECV* pData, DWORD cbData);
```

###### 3. Implementation of the Static Instance Function in the Cpp file

Normally this is where you'd implement all of your SimConnect callback handling, but in this case we are just going to cast the context reference to your class and pass it on to our custom instance function for further processing, e.g.

```
void CALLBACK MyClass::MyDispatchProcRD(SIMCONNECT_RECV* pData, DWORD cbData, void* pContext) {
    MyClass* procThis = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(pContext);
    procThis->DispatchProc(pData, cbData); 
}
```

###### 4. Implementation of the Custom Instance Function in the Cpp file

This is where you're going to implement all of your SimConnect handling. As this is now an instance function, you have access to the variables of the instance.

```cpp
void MyClass::DispatchProc(SIMCONNECT_RECV* pData, DWORD cbData) {
    switch (pData->dwID) {
    
    case SIMCONNECT_RECV_ID_SIMOBJECT_DATA: {
        SIMCONNECT_RECV_SIMOBJECT_DATA* pObjData = (SIMCONNECT_RECV_SIMOBJECT_DATA*)pData;
        ...
```

###### 5. Calling the Static Function

Just remember to pass the reference to your instance, i.e. `this`, when your are calling SimConnect dispatch, i.e.

```
SimConnect_CallDispatch(hSimConnect, MyDispatchProcRD, this);
```